# insert 'padding' between characters in HTML that functions as white space

Tags: html, css, character, space

my question may seem strange but I am trying to do something like this with HTML:

```
word1 word2 word3
  A     B     C
```

This by itself is easy but I want no space characters between A,B,C so that if a user searches by typing ABC, he can locate them. In other words, I want no white space between the characters but I would like them to each have a distance of X-characters from the next.

Is this feasible? Maybe with some css magic?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it's called padding. I think an introductory tutorial on CSS is in order.

Comment: @TylerH padding will require unnecessary html... magic is called `letter-spacing` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert padding… with padding! (or margin for inline elements)

```
<span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    margin: 0 4px;
}
```

Actual padding (for borders and stuff):

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 4px;
}
```

Or, if you're too lazy, you can use letter-spacing.

```
<span>ABC</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    letter-spacing: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `letter-spacing` property

Something like

```
<span>ABC<span>
```

CSS

```
span {
 letter-spacing:20px;
}
```

Comment: Letter spacing alone doesn't give the specified effect.

Comment: @rvighne What do you mean? Yes it does.

Comment: @rvighne re- read the question. "I want no space characters between A,B,C so that if a user searches by typing ABC, he can locate them"

The question is not about recreating the example OP gave. You might want to consider removing the down vote